# How to run shell script as regular user and then exec sudo in shell script?

Tags: command-line, bash, ssh, sudo, juju

How to run shell/bash script as normal user and exec sudo no password in the script

Comment: I found the answer - sudo -s
In my case I'm updating Juju model units/nodes to exec sysctl - the juju ssh command must be run as the juju user - a non privileged user account ubuntu (non su)
update kubernetes/calico nodes with loose rp_filter.

#!/bin/bash
juju ssh 9 sudo -s  sysctl -w net.ipv4.conf.all.rp_filter=0 && sysctl -p

- Using sudo -s  allows the script to continue with sysctl commands.